# How would I make this algorithm less redundant?

Tags: c, redundancy

I am fairly new to C and cannot figure out how to make the function `number_within_k_degrees()` less redundant. It visits the same nodes of the graph again and again, even though they may have already been visited. I thought to remove the initial setting of all values to `false` to reduce it somewhat, however I don't think that does much. Any tips on how to reduce or eliminate the redundant work would be very helpful. Thanks

```
void find_reachable_recursive(struct person *current, int steps_remaining,
                              bool *reachable){
    // mark current root person as reachable
    reachable[person_get_index(current)] = true;
    // now deal with this person's acquaintances
    if (steps_remaining > 0){
        int num_known = person_get_num_known(current);
        for (int i = 0; i < num_known; i++){
            struct person *acquaintance = person_get_acquaintance(current, i);
            find_reachable_recursive(acquaintance, steps_remaining - 1, reachable);
        }
    }
}

// computes the number of people within k degrees of the start person
int number_within_k_degrees(struct person *start, int total_people, int k){
    bool *reachable;
    int count;

    // maintain a boolean flag for each person indicating if they are visited
    reachable = malloc(sizeof(bool) * total_people);
    for (int i = 0; i < total_people; i++){
        reachable[i] = false;
    }

    // now search for all people who are reachable with k steps
    find_reachable_recursive(start, k, reachable);

    // all visited people are marked reachable, so count them
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < total_people; i++){
        if (reachable[i] == true){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: My first reaction is "Does it really matter to your performance?". If it does matter... I think you could count your people directly when you mark them as visited instead of going through everything again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought to remove the initial setting of all values to `false` to reduce it somewhat

That’s obviously a very bad idea: it *needs* to be initialised (to `false`) for correctness.

The real problem is that you never *test* whether a node has been visited yet. Since a note that was already visited does not need to be processed again, you can abort immediately:

```
void find_reachable_recursive(struct person *current, int steps_remaining,
                              bool *reachable){
    const int pindex = person_get_index(current);
    if (reachable[pindex]) return;
    // mark current root person as reachable
    reachable[pindex] = true;
    … rest of the code
```

Some further suggestions for improvements:

1. Don’t declare variables at the beginning of your functions, declare them where you initialise them. This improves readability by pulling declaration and usage of variables together.
2. Rather than calling `malloc` followed by setting values to `false` in a a loop, use [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc).
3. Don’t use boolean literals in tests. Code such as `if (reachable[i] == true)` is redundant, and should be written as `if (reachable[i])` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, they were very helpful!. I just have one other question, I understand what you said about testing whether a node has been visited, but how would I go about implementing that in the function above?